# log4j2 with servlet 3.0 container in WAS8.5 not working

Tags: log4j2

I am using log4j2.xml in web 3.0 container WAS8.5 servers.  I have all two jar files in class path. xml file also located in WEB-INF/classes/resources/log4j2.xml. I also made an entry in the web.xml file (Not sure if we need this). Getting below error.

```
    <context-param>
    <param-name>log4jConfiguration </param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/classes/resources/log4j2.xml</param-value>
   </context-param>
```

SystemErr     R ERROR StatusLogger No log4j2 configuration file found. Using default configuration: logging only errors to the console.

Added log4J-web-2.0 jar file. I turned on tracing in log4J.xml. I am removed context-param entry from web.xml as it is not necessary. This time, I am not geting error but no logger eaither. I am guessing server has has PARENT_FIRST class loding that may be overriding with IBM Log4J wich is old version?

10/3/14 8:15:43:606 CDT] 0000009e SystemOut     O 2014-10-03 08:15:43,606 DEBUG LoggerContext[name=
com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@de67afb1[war:eAdminEAR/eAdmin.war]
   Local ClassPath: C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes;C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-api-2.0.2.jar;C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-core-2.0.2.jar;C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent\WEB-INF\lib\log4j-web-2.0.2.jar;C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent
   Parent: com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader@fc165de9[PL][app]
   Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@e1a7ee0] started OK with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml].
[10/3/14 8:15:43:606 CDT] 0000009e webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [eAdminEAR#eAdmin.war]:.Log4jServletContextListener ensuring that Log4j starts up properly.
[10/3/14 8:15:43:606 CDT] 0000009e webcontainer  I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl addWebApplication SRVE0250I: Web Module eAdmin has been bound to default_host[*:9082,*:80,*:9445,*:5065,*:5064,*:443].
[10/3/14 8:15:43:621 CDT] 0000009e ApplicationMg A   WSVR0221I: Application started: eAdminEAR
[10/3/14 8:15:43:621 CDT] 0000009e CompositionUn A   WSVR0191I: Composition unit WebSphere:cuname=eAdminEAR in BLA WebSphere:blaname=eAdminEAR started.
[10/3/14 8:16:18:347 CDT] 0000009f ServletWrappe I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper init SRVE0242I: [eAdminEAR] [/eAdmin] [com.nglic.eadmin.servlets.TestServlet]: Initialization successful.
[10/3/14 8:16:18:378 CDT] 0000009f webapp        I com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp log SRVE0292I: Servlet Message - [eAdminEAR#eAdmin.war]:.Log4jServletFilter initialized.
[10/3/14 8:16:18:378 CDT] 0000009f SystemOut     O I am here....

Answer (score 0):

Please also include the log4j-web module in addition to the api and core modules.

Comment: I have updated my post with results. Please have a look. Thanks!

Comment: Delegation Mode: PARENT_FIRST, org.apache.logging.log4j.core.LoggerContext@e1a7ee0] started OK with configuration XmlConfiguration[location=C:\workspace\9.0\eAdmin\eAdmin\WebContent\WEB-INF\classes\log4j2.xml].

Comment: Hello, Could please help on this issues ?

Comment: Sorry, unable to look at this at the moment. Please raise a Jira ticket on the log4j2 issue tracker or ask on the log4j-user mailing list (Jira may be easier as it allows you to attach files).

Comment: I have submitted as an issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem was resolved. The issues is with log4j2.xml file. Root level was as trace and once I changed it to debug, I can see the logs in the console and in log files. Jeez....took 6 days to figureout.

```
 <Root level="debug" additivity="false">            
    <appender-ref ref="trace-log" level="debug"/>
    <appender-ref ref="error-log" level="error"/>
    <appender-ref ref="console-log" level="debug"/>

</Root>
```